# Infinispan (Red Hat Data Grid) in Openshift, with WebSphere Liberty

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, websphere-liberty, infinispan

We're trying to use Red Hat Data Grid (RHDG)/Infinispan in our OCP (4.5.36) cluster. We have the latest official RHDG Operator installed and a Cache type cluster defined. (Which is apparently a k8s StatefulSet.)

I've then configured a WebSphere Liberty container/Deployment to try to use that Infinispan cluster for its sessions, as described in https://github.com/WASdev/ci.docker#session-caching.

Both the Infinispan cluster and the Liberty Deployment are in the same Project/namespace.

However, the Liberty container fails to connect, and the Infinispan containers are reporting several warnings of their own.

The Liberty container "client" log:

```
INFINISPAN_SERVICE_NAME(original): session-infinispan
INFINISPAN_SERVICE_NAME(normalized): SESSION_INFINISPAN
INFINISPAN_HOST: 172.30.137.86
INFINISPAN_PORT: 11222
INFINISPAN_USER: developer
INFINISPAN_PASS: <redacted>

Launching defaultServer (WebSphere Application Server 21.0.0.3/wlp-1.0.50.cl210320210309-1101) on Eclipse OpenJ9 VM, version 1.8.0_282-b08 (en_US)
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server defaultServer has been launched.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0100I: This product is licensed for development, and limited production use. The full license terms can be viewed here: https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/license/base_ilan/ilan/21.0.0.3/lafiles/en.html
[AUDIT   ] CWWKG0093A: Processing configuration drop-ins resource: /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/configDropins/defaults/keystore.xml
[AUDIT   ] CWWKG0093A: Processing configuration drop-ins resource: /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/configDropins/overrides/infinispan-client-sessioncache.xml
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://payment-engine-6dcc5b6d5-jclx2:9080/payment/
[ERROR   ] ISPN004007: Exception encountered. Retry 10 out of 10
org.infinispan.client.hotrod.exceptions.TransportException:: ISPN004071: Connection to 172.30.137.86/172.30.137.86:11222 was closed while waiting for response.
[ERROR   ] SESN0307E: An exception occurred when initializing the cache. The exception is: org.infinispan.client.hotrod.exceptions.TransportException:: org.infinispan.client.hotrod.exceptions.TransportException:: ISPN004071: Connection to 172.30.137.86/172.30.137.86:11222 was closed while waiting for response.
    at org.infinispan.client.hotrod.impl.transport.netty.ActivationHandler.exceptionCaught(ActivationHandler.java:53)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:300)
...
```

What looks like the relevant part of the Inifinispan container log:

```
03:40:18,628 WARN  (SINGLE_PORT-ServerIO-4-2) [io.netty.handler.ssl.ApplicationProtocolNegotiationHandler] [id: 0xc39380c8, L:/10.254.0.248:11222 ! R:/10.254.2.65:32986] TLS handshake failed: io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record: a0061e21000003ffffffff0f0000
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1254)
```

(Actually, there are several Infinispan startup WARNs, mostly about deprecated capabilities. But this is the only one with a stack trace, so I'm jumping to the conclusion that it might be "the culprit")

Also, this is the Infinispan Service, so you can see the IP and port match what the Liberty container is using:

[image: Infinispan Service details]

Comment: This looks like a mismatch how Liberty is expecting to connect (SSL/TLS) and the config of RHDG. can you post the YAML or definition that you used to create the RHDG cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working through this on [the Infinispan chat service](https://infinispan.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/118645-infinispan/topic/RHDG.20OCP.20Liberty.20failure), it does appear that there's incorrect or incomplete setup of SSL/TLS.

I had attempted to remove encryption in the Infinispan cluster, but I either didn't sufficiently restart components or you can't change it after the fact. Removing the cluster and recreating with it disabled, though, enabled the Liberty communication to work.

The following CR YAML works:

```yaml
apiVersion: infinispan.org/v1
kind: Infinispan
metadata:
  name: session-infinispan
spec:
  replicas: 1
  service:
    type: Cache 
  security:
    endpointEncryption:
      type: None
```

Now to pursue what's missing from the Liberty setup to make use of SSL correctly. The Infinispan chat conversation says that this Liberty XML setup from the official image:

```xml
<server>
  <featureManager>
    <feature>sessionCache-1.0</feature>
  </featureManager>
  <httpSessionCache libraryRef="InfinispanLib">
    <properties infinispan.client.hotrod.server_list="${INFINISPAN_HOST}:${INFINISPAN_PORT}"/>
    <properties infinispan.client.hotrod.marshaller="org.infinispan.commons.marshall.JavaSerializationMarshaller"/>
    <properties infinispan.client.hotrod.java_serial_whitelist=".*"/>
    <properties infinispan.client.hotrod.auth_username="${INFINISPAN_USER}"/>
    <properties infinispan.client.hotrod.auth_password="${INFINISPAN_PASS}"/>
    <properties infinispan.client.hotrod.auth_realm="default"/>
    <properties infinispan.client.hotrod.sasl_mechanism="DIGEST-MD5"/>
    <properties infinispan.client.hotrod.auth_server_name="infinispan"/>
  </httpSessionCache>
  <httpSessionCache enableBetaSupportForInfinispan="true"/> <!-- TODO remove once no longer gated -->
  <library id="InfinispanLib">
    <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/infinispan" includes="*.jar"/>
  </library>
</server>
```

[Needs the following properties added](https://infinispan.org/docs/infinispan-operator/master/operator.html#hotrod_properties-clients):

```
# Encryption
infinispan.client.hotrod.sni_host_name=$SERVICE_HOSTNAME
# Path to the TLS certificate.
# Clients automatically generate trust stores from certificates.
infinispan.client.hotrod.trust_store_path=/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/service-ca.crt
```